# Strange app crash when pushing the button

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Hello I learning how to develop Android applications. I have a fragment in a second activity and I want when pushing the button to return to the main activity. My code is the one below:

```
  public class NoteEditFragment extends Fragment {

private String title,summary;
private EditText editTextTitle, editTextSummary;
//private Button saveEditButton;
public NoteEditFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentEdit = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_edit, container, false);

    editTextTitle = (EditText)fragmentEdit.findViewById(R.id.editNoteTitle);
    editTextSummary= (EditText) fragmentEdit.findViewById(R.id.editNoteSummary);
   // saveEditButton = (Button) fragmentEdit.findViewById(R.id.editSaveButton);

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    title = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.NOTETITLE);
    summary=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.NOTESUMMARY);

    editTextTitle.setText(title);
    editTextSummary.setText(summary);
  /*  saveEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }

    });
    */
    return fragmentEdit;
}

public void onSaveMethod(View view){

 Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
    }
```

}

When I define the onclick listener my self , the code inside the block of comments it works, however when I am attaching the onClick attribute into the XML and implementing the method the app crashes. From the log I could not understand what is happening. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

The `onClick` attribute in XML **only** works with the `Activity`, so your `onSaveMethod` would need to be declared in your `Activity`, even though you are inflating it as part of a Fragment.

If you are using Fragments, you must use `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Seeing your comment I remember having read it somewhere but I could not think of it now. Thank you a lot.....!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Remove attribute `android:onClick="onSaveMethod"` from button `editSaveButton`.

**2.** Add `onClick` listener to your button `programmatically` from `Fragment`.

**3.** Remove parameter `View` from method `onSaveMethod()` and call this method from `onClick()`.

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ............
    ...............

    saveEditButton = (Button) fragmentEdit.findViewById(R.id.editSaveButton);
    saveEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSaveMethod();
        }
    });

    return fragmentEdit;
}

public void onSaveMethod() {

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Hope this will help~